# Copy Data To Different Column if Row is Filtered: Spotfire, R, Data Function

Tags: spotfire

I'm looking to transfer a data column from one column to another after I click a button. I do not want to transfer the whole column, just rows where the name column is selected in a filter.

My train of thought was:
1) get a list of strings that are filtered
2) then loop through the rows of the table
3) check on that row if the name column is in the list
4) If so, then copy the data, if not leave the value in the copy

I've accomplished the 1) by creating a document property of the filtered values separated by commas. So "A, C" if A and C are filtered.

Table before data function call:

[image: Before Data Table]

Table after data function call when A & C are filtered.

[image: After Data Table]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a calculated column?

```
 If ([Name] in ("A","C"),[Value],[Copy])
```

Add a multi line ctrl doc prop to replace "A","C" in the expression with ${aDocProp} that holds your Name filtered values on a text area.

Comment: null changes the column to nothing. Is there a way to keep the original value ?

Comment: Change "null" to "[Copy]"

Comment: You've got a comment from another user posted as a (now deleted) answer. See this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/3qa9f.png